# Problems with my webusercontroler(Parser error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webusercontrol

I have made a webusercontrol on my asp.net webforms application. But I get this parser error when I try to run it

> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'uc1:WebUserControl1'.

I have this code in my sitemaster:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And this is my WebUserControl that I created in my solution:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="GameShops.WebUserControl1" EnableViewState="true" %>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="usrlblAntalVaror" runat="server" Text="Inga Varor"></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="usrlblTotalpris" runat="server" Text="0 kr"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="usrDdlVaror" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="148px" 
         AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="usrbtnTabort" runat="server" AlternateText="Ta Bort" 
        Height="26px" ImageUrl="~/Image/RecycleBin.png" Width="29px" CommandName="usrbtnTabort_click" OnCommand="usrbtnTabort_click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="usrTillKassanBtn" runat="server" Text="Till Kassan" 
        onclick="usrTillKassanBtn_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
<p></p>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please add the directive in the master page with the user control path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the usercontrol on your master page.

```
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl.ascx" TagName="WebUserControl1" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
```